# Can I use ExtJS table layout for this?

Tags: extjs

I want to put five `textareafield` components into a `container` such that they fill the whole `container`:

```
    33%       33%       33%
+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         | 50%
|         |         |         |
|         +---------+---------+
|         |         |         | 50%
|         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is there any better layout to use than two `vbox` containers inside a `hbox` container?

This looks more like a tabular layout. But how can I tell textareas to fill the whole screen inside a `table` layout, and the table columns that they should take 33% width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a main `box` container with three panels inside, one `fit` and two `vbox`, always setting `flex:1`.

Look, you could use a table layout but that would be better if you knew the exact dimension of every container inside your table, if you want to work with proportions, `hbox`, `fit` a and `vbox` is the best way (That is why they are there).

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.MyPanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

        requires: [
            'Ext.panel.Panel',
            'Ext.form.field.TextArea'
        ],


        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        title: 'My textarea table',

        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textareafield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Label'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textareafield',
                        flex: 1,
                        fieldLabel: 'Label'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textareafield',
                        flex: 1,
                        fieldLabel: 'Label'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textareafield',
                        flex: 1,
                        fieldLabel: 'Label'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textareafield',
                        flex: 1,
                        fieldLabel: 'Label'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    });

    Ext.create('Fiddle.view.MyPanel',{
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```